# Why Is My While Loop Blowing Up Inside My Button Void

Tags: c#, linq, int, primes

I decided to sit down today and try and make a simple prime counter program where you enter the sub-rime of two primes and then the program tells you the multipliers used to get that product.  Although it seems to crash.  After process of elimination through comment out code I concluded it must be the while loop that I crashing this whole program.  Does anyone have any answers to why this might be not working?

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace A_Prime
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int multiplier1 = 1;
        int multiplier2 = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (true)
            {

                int Product = multiplier1 * multiplier2;

                label2.Text = multiplier1 + "x" + multiplier2 + "=" + Product;

                string product = Product.ToString();



                if (product == textBox1.Text)
                {
                    label3.Text = "Your Multipliers Are" + multiplier1 + "x" + multiplier2;


                }
                else
                {
                    multiplier1++;

                    multiplier2++;
                }




            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a never ending loop

Comment: Your loop never stops looping. Once you click the button, the program flow is gone for good.

Comment: put `break;` statement in while loop based on your requirement, or else it will be never ending loop, will cause stack overflow.

Comment: So you patiently stepped through the code in the debugger and ...?

Comment: HABO not everyone realizes the code, at the time I more forogt about the break;  I am just a young developer trying to self teach C#  and I am only doing this for recreation.

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite loop. You never break out of your `while` loop, you need a `break` statement somewhere. Looking at your code, it looks like once you find the multipliers and set the `label3.Text` value, you are done and should break out of the loop.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         while (true)
         {
            int Product = multiplier1 * multiplier2;
            label2.Text = multiplier1 + "x" + multiplier2 + "=" + Product;
            string product = Product.ToString();    

            if (product == textBox1.Text)
            {
                label3.Text = "Your Multipliers Are" + multiplier1 + "x" + multiplier2;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                multiplier1++;
                multiplier2++;
            }    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no exit strategy or condition in your while loop. Introduce any exit condition along with this keyword

```
if(exit_condition)
   break;
```

Answer (score 0):

the condition that while loop execudes the rest of your code is always true. As i see there is no part of your code that you can change that bool value, so what you have is an infinite loop... Try changing the while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have a break in your loop and you only get numbers, which have a natural number square root, because your calculating just n^2 in the loop